# Visual Studio IDE Error - Can't Open/Import File

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ide

in my VS 2010 Ultimate IDE,whenever i try to open a file, add an icon in toolstrip, create a new project (anything that involves an open dialogbox) nothing happens. the dialogbox won't show and i can't proceed with the task im doing. it was working before but suddenly this problem came. i have already tried:

- Running in Administrator
- Resetting the Workspace (Import and Export)
- Reinstalling VS 2010 (tried my installer in another pc and it worked)
- Starting VS in /SafeMode

i have uploaded a video on what is happening in my IDE. [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrukE0hyFuE&feature=youtu.be)

Any form of help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: You need to get your machine stable again.  Use SysInternals' AutoRuns utility to disable shell extensions.  Start by disabling everything that doesn't have a Microsoft copyright.  Then enable the ones you can't live without one by one.  Uninstall the evildoer.

Comment: where can i find/run SysInternals' AutoRuns?

Comment: Is google down today?  Don't be helpless.